# What happened when curator leaderlatch lose connection?

Tags: apache-curator

According to this page:[Curator Leader Latch](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-latch.html), when the leader lose connection with zookeeper server, there will not be a leader until the connection is re-established. What does it mean? If the leader never reconnected to the server again, then other participants will never become leader?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is that the instance suffering from the connection is LOST or SUSPENDED will not become leader. One of the other instances on another JVMs may become a leader.